# Spring boot - expose common application properties with different names

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp

I have a requirement where I need my custom application properties to act as aliases to  various common application properties that spring provides for different packages.

Example:
Whenever I set a value to the application property foo.host, it should set the value for spring.rabbit.host property.

Similarly setting the value for foo.port should set the value for spring.rabbitmq.port.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can, you can add these to your **application.properties**:

```
spring.rabbit.host=${foo.host}
spring.rabbit.port=${foo.port}
```

However, if you still provide `spring.rabbit.host` via system properties, as an environment variable or as direct argument then it will take precedence over foo config.